# TFJS Node Model Not Loading Correctly, No Functions Available

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to import a Keras model into Tensorflow.JS using Node and no explicit errors have occurred but, when I try to use my imported model, it has no functions available so it obviously hasn't been loaded correctly. I have opted to use Express to host a static HTTP file server, and I am hosting the model.json as well as the 20 binary shard files.

I presume that if there was a problem reading this model, there would be an obvious error (as I have encountered this previously and had to modify my Express code to fix it...)

**Local Model:**

[image: File Structure - if it helps!]

**Static HTTP Server:**

```
file_server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/model')); // Where the model resides
```

**Loading the model:**

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const model = tf.loadLayersModel('http://127.0.0.1:3001/model.json');
console.log(typeof(model)); // Returns 'object'

var predictions = model.predict(image_tensor).data(); 
// TypeError: model.predict is not a function
```

I have tried loading the model in an async function, using await, and attempting to predicting asynchronously but the problem remained the same.

If there is any more information required, please let me know, I am very new to Node and web development in general, so please forgive any obvious oversights!

Thanks again, Josh

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(model)`. It should show you all the associated functions and attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. After modifying the code to be async, I used that statement and got a huge, 3000 line output (https://pastebin.com/raw/jtRM78HD) with lots of attributes of the model and its layers, but no mention of the predict function, or any other function that should be present such as model.summary().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around a bit, I figured out that this wasn’t an issue loading in the model, it was a problem with the model being in block-scope. Changing const to var seemed to fix this. I don’t know why only the functions weren’t available, but this code seemed to fix it:

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
var model = "";

exports.loadModel = async function() {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://127.0.0.1:3001/model.json');
}
```